# js files are automatically deleted - adminhtml/web/js/components/use-parent-settings

Tags: requirejs, static-content-deploy, developer-mode, production-mode, production

In my M 2.2.6  I can not enter the Category section of dashboard, 
the spining is turn around.

When I check the console, some of JS has 404 error

In  -  adminhtml/web/js/components/use-parent-settings -

```
select.js
single-checkbox.js
textarea.js
toggle-disabled-mixin.js
```

I add it manual via SFTP then  run

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Problem temporarily resolved, but after one day, I can not enter the category section on dashboard again. and again.

On the other hand
I can not set to production to run

```
 bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```

It gives an error like

```
The directory "/srv/public_html/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/tr_TR/Magento_Catalog/js/components/use-parent-settings/toggle-disabled-mixin.js" cannot be deleted Warning!rmdir(/srv/public_html/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/tr_TR/Magento_Catalog/js/components/use-parent-settings/toggle-disabled-mixin.js): Not a directory
```

As it appears that the symlinks are part of your deployment system,  will need to fix the links to point to the appropriate place/file but I can not handle.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run command in this sequence

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production --skip-compilation
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f en_GB tr_TR
```

After running this commands you'll not get any issues then.

Hope this will work for you!

Comment: Yes it is working
Thank you 
 but now  I can not switch to developer mode . It gives same error..

I can not reach any section on admin Dashboard
----
https://a4yewu6o72si64b8.mojostratus.io/static/version1574590607/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/requirejs/require.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404

---

Comment: @ozanyeni, I can see this file is available on that path can you please open that URL once ?

Comment: Please run this command once **php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f en_GB tr_TR**, and then check once.

Comment: Yes I solved Thank you. But I can not switch to developer :)

Comment: If you want to switch from production to developer then please run first command which is available in my answer and let me know if you will get any errors there then.

Comment: php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer i used that thenbi gotThe directory "/srv/public_html/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/tr_TR/Magento_Catalog/js/components/use-parent-settings/toggle-disabled-mixin.js" cannot be deleted

Comment: There may be permission issue. Can you please run this **sudo chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/**

Comment: Sorry,
Same result 
The directory "/srv/public_html/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/tr_TR/Magento_Catalog/js/components/use-parent-settings/toggle-disabled-mixin.js" cannot be deleted Warning!rmdir(/srv/public_html/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/tr_TR/Magento_Catalog/js/components/use-parent-settings/toggle-disabled-mixin.js): Not a directory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101428/discussion-between-ozan-yeni-and-kishan-savaliya).